# Eclipse Plugin uncommon dependency restriction

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

1. There is a plugin X with open source code.
2. I have cloned it and added my Class C. Lets call my version Xm (modified).
3. My plugin Y depends on class C.

The question:
How can I achieve that plugin Y is only installable when class C is available (i.e. plugin Xm is installed)?

I could make it by adding a version dependency, but we remember that there is original plugin X that can have even higher version then my Xm and doesn't have my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your Xm is not the same as X, so it should have a different plug-in ID. Thus there are no mixing the original version with your version.

Alternatively, you can consider using a fragment to X with just your added functionality. And then have a feature with the fragment and Y.

*EDIT:* Note that the use of fragments is normally only possible when you add new classes or resources to the existing plug-in. Unless you play certain dubious tricks with OSGi and the class path of the original bundle, you cannot replace - or hot-fix - an existing class.

Comment: The solution with fragment looks interesting. Could you recommend some article/example about using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Create feature G that includes feature F and plug-in Y.

Comment: I think my problem description was bad. When I said 'feature' I didn't mean Eclipse installable unit feature, but just a new functionality.